# Как узнать активен ли фрагмент/активити

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, activity, push

В андроид приложении нужно реализовать функциональность чата.
Информация о входящем сообщении приходит через Firebase Push и сохраняется в локальной БД.

Что хочу: если при приходе push открыта активити (фрагмент чата в MainActivity), то обновить данные, если открыт другой фрагмент или приложение свернуто - создать и показать Notification

Основной вопрос: как узнать что в данный момент на экране открыт чат?
Информацию во фрагмент можно отправить sendBroadcast, но как узнать что фрагмент ее не получил (и в этом случае создать уведомление)?

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант в MainActivity сохранять текущий фрагмент.
Допустим у вас есть метод для смены фрагментов, получаемый фрагмент держите как переменную активности.

```
 public void switchToFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.frame, fragment)
                .addToBackStack(null) // что бы не делать стек фрагментов
                .commitAllowingStateLoss();
        currentFragment = fragment;
    }
```

В данном примере currentFragment и выступает той самой переменной.
Далее делайте проверку:

```
if (currentFragment instanceof ChatFragment ) {
   // ваш код при открытом чате
}
```

ChatFrament это название вашего класса фрагмента в котором и реализован чат.

Еще видел вот такую реализацию:

```
ChatFrament test = (ChatFrament) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("tag");
if (test != null && test.isVisible()) {
     // ваш код при открытом чате
}
```

В данном примере нужно будет присваивать теги для фрагментов, тогда к ним можно будет обратиться и узнать активен ли он.

В таком случае метод для смены фрагментов я бы делал вот так:

```
public void switchToFragment(Fragment fragment, String tag) {
            getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.frame, fragment, tag)
                    .addToBackStack(null) // что бы не делать стек фрагментов
                    .commitAllowingStateLoss();
        }
```